# How can i cancel asyntask and show toast message

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i received json data from service. i use asynctask to get the data. when the data is empty i want to cancel the asynstask and show the user some message.

```
        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

            // Progress Dialog
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            private LoadCategories mTask;

    .....

     /**
             * Listening to Load More button click event
             * */
            btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {                
                    if (URL_CATEGORY == null || URL_CATEGORY == "")
                    {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"URL est vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                    else
                    { // Starting a new async task
                        //new LoadCategories().execute();
                        mTask = new LoadCategories();
                        mTask.execute();
                        }               
                }
            });

    ....

     class LoadCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("en cours...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);

                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_CATEGORY, "GET",
                        params); 

                if (json == null || json == "")
                {
                    mTask.cancel(true);
    //               if(isCancelled())
    //               {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Donée sont vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                    synchronized(this) {
                        while (json.length() == 0) {
                            if(mTask.isCancelled()) 
                            { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Donée sont vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}                      
                        }
                    }   
                }
                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("Categories JSON: ", "> " + json);  
                return json;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
                try {
                    categories = new JSONArray(json);
                    categoryList.clear();
                    if (categories != null) {
                        // looping through All albums
                        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
.....
```

my problem the programm never cancel and show the message.
when i debug it, it enter to my condition

```
if (json == null || json == "")
            {
                mTask.cancel(true);
//               if(isCancelled())
//               {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Donée sont vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                synchronized(this) {
                    while (json.length() == 0) {
                        if(mTask.isCancelled()) 
                        { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Donée sont vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}                      
                    }
                }   
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this...

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // code
        if (json.equals(null) || json.equals("")){
            if(mTask.isCancelled()) break;
            return null;
        }

       return json;
    }
```

onPostExecute

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
     if(json.equals(null) || json.equals("")){
         // Make a toast Message
     }else{
        // your code
     }
```

no need to cancel your Async task....

Answer (score 0):

Just check isCancelled() once in a while in background of async class:

```
 protected String doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Android Documentation you could override `onCancelled()` method that will be called if an AsyncTask is being cancelled

> Cancelling a task
>   A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking
>   cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to
>   isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method,
>   onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked
>   after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is
>   cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return
>   value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if
>   possible (inside a loop for instance.)

or you can also check isCancelled in your loop for example :

```
if (isCancelled()) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "AsyncTask is Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
}
else
{
   // some process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with a cancel event, override `onCancelled()` method of `AsyncTask` in your `LoadCategories` class. Move codes for showing the toast message into your own `onCancelled()` method.

However, I think that `mTask.cancel()` is not necessary. I recommend to check `json` value and decide to show the toast message in `onPostExecute()`.